# reviewing a facebook app without a store id

Tags: facebook

I am building a windows camera app where people can login to their facebook account to post the photo.
In order to get user_photos and publish_actions permissions I'm asked to add a platform.
When adding windows app as a platform, I'm asked to add a Windows Store ID, which is something I don't have, the app is supposed to run on a dedicated computer and not to be used by the general public.

**Is there any way to gain user_photos and publish_actions permissions without specifying a Windows Store ID?**

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you have to register your app and a get Windows Store ID in order to gain those permissions.
If you need some help with setting it up, I recommend reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2015/02/12/integrating-facebook-authentication-in-universal-windows-apps.aspx) guide.